# SELECT only first and last results

Tags: mysql, sql

A client can have more than one equipment (SerialNo). Each equipment has a cost and every month there is data recorded for each equipment. I'm trying to select only the first and last result for each equipment based on the queried period.

```
"
SELECT i.SerialNo
     , p.Name
     , c.Cost
     , ci.DataDate
     , ci.Data
     ,
  FROM install i
  JOIN product p USING (ProductId)
  JOIN counter c USING (InstallId)
  JOIN counter_item ci USING (CounterId)
 WHERE i.ClientId LIKE $clientId
   AND MONTH(ci.DataDate) BETWEEN $mStart AND $mEnd
 ";
```

This select works but it retrieves all records between the starting date and finishing date.

I tried, to get the top results and figured I would use A UNION ALL to combine with the bottom results (ci.DataDate ASC), but it's not working. I only get the first record encounter.

```
GROUP BY i.SerialNo
ORDER BY ci.DataDate DESC
```

It's like ORDER BY has no effect at all.

Comment: Is the `SerialNo` column a unique key for each row in the table?

Comment: Have you tried `... ORDER BY ci.DataDate ASC LIMIT 1 union all ... ORDER BY ci.DataDate DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: how about `order by` and just take the first one, then the last one =)

Comment: SerialNo is unique in the install table. If i use LIMIT 1, then I only get one equipment, instead of all of them.

Comment: The ORDER BY doesn't have the desired effect, because it gets applied *after* selecting the data. So you group by SerialNo, which gets you c.Cost, ci.DataDate and ci.Data arbitrarily chosen, because no aggregation function is specified, and only then the data gets sorted.

Comment: This SELECT does NOT work. Can you spot why?

Comment: No, I can't spot it. But the sql as it was before you edited it was working.

Comment: No. I changed the formatting to make the error easier to spot. That's all. The error is repeated in an answer below, given before my edit

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're playing games. I there is an error just go ahead and point it out. All I know is that for the comma after the ci.Data will throw an error in my WordPress environment, that's why I don't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In counter_item you find the first and last DataDate per CounterId for the time range. So find these first by aggregation and use this information in order to join the desired records:

```
SELECT i.SerialNo,
       p.Name,
       c.Cost,
       ci.DataDate,
       ci.Data
FROM install i
JOIN product p ON p.ProductId = i.ProductId
JOIN counter c ON c.InstallId = i.InstallId
JOIN 
(
  SELECT CounterId, MIN(DataDate) AS MinDate, MAX(DataDate) AS MaxDate
  FROM counter_item
  WHERE MONTH(DataDate) BETWEEN $mStart AND $mEnd
  GROUP BY CounterId
) minmax ON minmax.CounterId = c.CounterId
JOIN counter_item ci ON ci.CounterId = minmax.CounterId
                     AND ci.DataDate IN (minmax.MinDate, minmax.MaxDate)
WHERE i.ClientId LIKE $clientId
ORDER BY i.SerialNo, ci.DataDate
```

Comment: This is similar with (SELECT ci.DataDate FROM counter JOIN counter_item ci USING (CounterId) JOIN install i USING (InstallId) WHERE i.ClientId LIKE $clientId ORDER BY ci.DataDate ASC LIMIT 1) DataDate, which seams to be working

Comment: With LIMIT you get the first record after ORDER BY. You want the newest *and* oldest record, but it can only *either* be the oldest *or* the newest record first. Moreover you said you want the first and last record *per SerialNo*, but LIMIT gives you *one* result record for *all* records.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was going to use a UNION ALL where the second select is order by desc. I will give your solution a run and see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in next way, here is just general idea of how that could be done:

```
select * from table
where 
    ([row] = (select max([row]) from table ) or 
    [Date] = (select min([row]) from table ))
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also be able to use a cross apply. Something like this, untested rough sample:

```
SELECT i.SerialNo,
    p.Name,
    c.Cost,
    MIN(ci.DataDate) as MinDate,
    b.MaxDate,
    ci.Data,
 FROM install i
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT  
    MAX(ci.DataDate) as MaxDate
 FROM install     
 JOIN counter_item ci USING (CounterId)
 WHERE i.ClientId LIKE $clientId
 AND MONTH(ci.DataDate) BETWEEN $mStart AND $mEnd) b
 WHERE i.ClientId LIKE $clientId
 AND MONTH(ci.DataDate) BETWEEN $mStart AND $mEnd
 GROUP BY i.SerialNo
 ORDER BY ci.DataDate DESC
```

Comment: There is no cross apply in mysql

Comment: Question has a 'sql' tag. I thought maybe he had options.